# SwiftUI NavigationBar sliver sliding down creates unexpected behavior

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationbar

When using the NavigationView in SwiftUI, it creates lots of unexpected behavior when sliding down on the navigation bar to when it would collapse. I am using a search bar as well(searchable directly on the List). I am unsure what is causing this but it may have to do with having sections on my List.

Here is some source code that works for me. I am running this on a real iPhone and it creates this behavior.

https://utilities.awesomeplayer.tech/send/f.php?h=1I-fJPHl&p=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE! I found the answer to this and that this is caused by adding .animation() to the SwiftUI List itself. While this does give a nice animation and controls the animation while updating, deleting, etc., it controls the animations of the whole navigation bar itself as well. I found this by tweaking the duration part of `.animation(.default(duration: 1)) to four and noticing a noticeable difference in how it slides down: it slides down slower.

[image]

There is a warning I was ignoring from Xcode complaining about a deprecation. After some research, I replaced it with `.animation(.default, value: UUID())` and that seemed to work perfectly.